# Date-picker in v-menu is not showing up (Vuetify)

Tags: vue.js, datepicker, vuetify.js

I have a v-menu that's supposed to let user select a date, and that date will be displayed on a text-field.

Here's the v-menu:

```
<v-menu v-model="selectDate
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">    
        <v-text-field v-on="on" :value="eventDate" label="Event Date" readonly></v-text-field>
    </template>
    <v-date-picker @input="selectDate = false" v-model="eventDate" no-title ></v-date-picker>
</v-menu>
```

and the script:

```
<script>
export default{
    data() {
        return{
            selectDate: false,
            eventDate: null,
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I've been trying to read the documentation for [Menus](https://dev.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/menus/) and this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57696615/vuetify-how-to-fix-v-date-picker-not-showing-the-chosen-date-in-the-text-field) was pretty useful, but it's still not popping up. I initially started from this [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KQJFLQO9ri4) but it's outdated.

Changing  `:value="eventDate"` to `v-model="eventDate"` still doesn't make it pop up.

Comment: There is a syntax error in there (missing `">` at the end of the opening `v-menu` tag), otherwise this works as expected in Vuetify 2. Are you sure you are not using Vuetify 3?

Comment: Oh, snap. I'm using Vuetify 3. It's apparently very easy to just do that in Vuetify 3, just use a ```v-text-field``` with ```type="date"```. Thank you!